# Ways to chalk a grass baseball field?

Tags: baseball, softball

We are having a baseball game with ~20 friends and are using a school's baseball field. Anyone is allowed to use the field. However, it is all grass and doesn't have any chalk lines. Is there anyway to easily make some chalk lines? Doesn't have to be chalk, just some way to mark the lines. I appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a can of spray paint that can work great and is pretty quick.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on what we did to solve this, we got a roll of white duct tape.

The advantage was that it is temporary and can be removed so we weren't "damaging school property".The disadvantage is that it gets shifted or destroyed as people run on it.

So for anyone interested, its a relatively cheap and very visible, but temporary solution.